# How to find menu height

Tags: android, xml

i want to create fixed navigation layout, but there is a problem when i rotate device, margin-top of this layout is more than it has to be, so the question - how can i find height of this dark-blue header ( to use it as margin ), or maybe there is another way

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/panel_border"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would go with this:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

This attribute indicates correct height of the `ActionBar` / `Toolbar`.
 The `Toolbars` height may be different for different APIs and that's the reason you should use `?android:attr` or `?attr` (when using support library).
 `?` means that it comes from internal Android resources.

Answer (score 0):

Let the android support library do it for you. Like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <! -- Your View -->

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/panel_border"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

take a look at [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Comment: Support library is awesome, but how can it help me

Comment: hard coded margins is a bad idea in this case I have updated  my answer to fit your example